# Getting error in get_template Python

Tags: python, templates, django-templates

I have write down this code in Python Django to use template and getting error.
My Django Version:  1.8.3

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template  
from django.template import Context 

def hello_template (request):
    name = "Jatin"
    t = get_template('hello.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'name': name}, request))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /hello_template/

'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```